# Translate a string from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1

Tags: java

I'm reading some text data from my database that is in `UTF-8` charset. But i need to generate a file with `ISO-8859-1` charset.

To do this I'm using the following code.

```
StringBuilder filaStr = new StringBuilder();
filaStr.append("INGENIERÍA DE EJECUCIÓN EN ADMINISTRACIÓN");//this is a UTF-8 string got from my database
Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
Charset iso8859_1 = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
CharsetDecoder decoder = utf8.newDecoder();
CharsetEncoder encoder = iso8859_1.newEncoder();
CharBuffer decodedCB = decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(filaStr.toString().getBytes()));
ByteBuffer encodedBB = encoder.encode(decodedCB);
pw.write(new String(encodedBB.array()));//pw is the PrintWriter that writes in the file
pw.write(new String(encodedBB.array(), iso8859_1));
```

When I open the file with the text editor using `UTF-8` charset I see this:

```
INGENIER�A DE EJECUCI�N EN ADMINISTRACI�N
INGENIERÍA DE EJECUCIÓN EN ADMINISTRACIÓN
```

And when I open it using `ISO-8859-1` I see this:

```
INGENIERï¿½A DE EJECUCIï¿½N EN ADMINISTRACIï¿½N
INGENIERÃA DE EJECUCIÃN EN ADMINISTRACIÃN
```

The desired result is to print `INGENIERÍA DE EJECUCIÓN EN ADMINISTRACIÓN` in `ISO-8859-1` charset.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the PrintWriter, this must be initialized with the desired charset.

`PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file, "ISO-8859-1");` Solved the problem and even no `CharsetDecoder` and `CharsetEncoder` were needed.